# testing facebook like button offline

Tags: facebook, testing

Is there a way to test what information is being sent to the like button while my site is still offline? At the moment, the like button shows up but pressing it produces an error, I can't test if the right info is going to be passed to facebook once the implementation goes live.

Comment: Write a custom fake Facebook server and configure it in /etc/hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your app in "sandbox" mode, then it remains offline for all but the registered developers for it. That will allow you to test it, whilst stopping others from seeing it.

Comment: where do I find Sandbox mode?

Comment: Click "Edit Settings" for your app at https://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php - select the "Advanced" tab, and ensure "Sandbox mode" is set to "Enable"

Comment: Done, but they still show up if someone views my profile directly.

Comment: What do you mean by "they still show up"? If you're worried about wall postings, etc. appearing on your profile, you'll also need to set up some test users. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

Comment: Thanks for this, has been a big help (hence +1), but hasn't answered the offline issue.